# How to find out if a generic type is 'comparable' during runtime?

Tags: go, generics

I'd like to write a generic `equals` method which works like this:

```golang
func equals[T any](a, b T) bool {
  if hasEqualsMethod(T) {
    return a.Equals(b)
  else if isComparable(T) {
    return a == b
  }
  panic("type cannot be compared")
}
```

For this, I created an interface `Comparable`:

```golang
type Comparable[T any] interface {
    // Equals returns true if the receiver and the argument are equal.
    Equals(T) bool
}
```

I can check if an argument to equals implements this `Comparable` interface like this:

```golang
func equals[T any](a, b T) bool {
    aComp, ok := any(a).(Comparable[T])
    if ok {
        return aComp.Equals(b)
    }
    ...
```

However, so far I found no possibility to find out if `a` also satisfies the `comparable` constraint and convert it into something on which `==` can be used.

**Is there any way to find out if a generic type `T any` is `comparable` during runtime and, if so, compare it using `==`?**

I could restrict my whole code to work only on `comparable` generic types, but I'd like to give users the possibility to manually add an `equals` method, if their type happens to be not `comparable` (e.g. because it's based on a slice).

Comment: Generics are handled at compile time not at runtime, so if the type parameter is not `comparable`, you cannot compile the code using `==` in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it compiles with equality operators, it's comparable. A type parameter constrained by `any` isn't comparable by definition: it could be literally anything, including `func() error`.

Therefore it's not possible to write your `equals` function with static typing. You have to use reflection or admit only arguments that implement an "equaler" interface, like your own `Comparable[T any]`.

With reflection, you can use [`Value#Comparable`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Comparable):

```
func equals[T any](a, b T) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    if v.Comparable() {
        u := reflect.ValueOf(b)
        return v.Equal(u)
    }
    panic("type cannot be compared")
}
```

In this case the usage of generics may help ensure at compile time that `a` and `b` have the same exact type, so that `v.Equal(u)` isn't meaningless, instead of declaring `equals(a, b any)`.

With an "equaler" interface, you have to provide named types that implement it in order to convert predeclared types and call the method on them:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(equals(EqualerFloat64(5.57), EqualerFloat64(5.57)))
}

type Equaler[T any] interface {
    Equal(T) bool
}

type EqualerFloat64 float64

func (f EqualerFloat64) Equal(f2 EqualerFloat64) bool {
    return f == f2
}

func equals[T Equaler[T]](a, b T) bool {
    return a.Equal(b)
}
```